Cambar ruta de ADVs en Android Studio
Tengo un problema, mi nombre de usuario en windows contiene carácteres con acentos, ya lo se, fué un error en su dia y ya no lo puedo cambiar.
El problema es que al crear AVDs en Android Studio e intentar ejecutarlos me da error ya que la ruta para el adv contiene carácteres "prohibidos".
Existe alguna forma de escoger la ruta donde se crean los ADVs o de solucionar este problema?
Muchas gracias.

Encontré 2 opciones:

Crear el dispositivo virtual por línea de comandos, ya que así se puede especificar dónde se debe guardar.
Esto se puede hacer mediante la herramienta avdmanager. Este es un ejemplo de la documentación:
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"

Para elegir dónde se guardará el dispositivo virtual debes agregar la opción -p seguida de la ruta.

Modificar las variables de entorno.
Modificar la variable ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME a la ruta que deseas guardar todo lo referido a los emuladores debería funcionar.
En el enlace puedes encontrar otras variables de entorno que podrías querer modificar. Como ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_USER_HOME o ANDROID_AVD_HOME.
Modificar la variable ANDROID_USER_HOME debería hacer que todo el contenido de la carpeta .android se busque en otro lugar, incluyendo lo referido a los emuladores.


